# Problems playing Youtube clips on mobile using the iFrame API

Tags: mobile, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

I am embedding youtube clips on my website (using the iframe API), and there's an annoying issue when watching it on mobile. For most clips, I am setting a start and end parameters. I can see the clip on the device loading fine, the marker even jumps to the start position, but then (and only on some videos) all I get is the spinner running infinitely without playing the clip.
I tried pausing and playing again and I noticed that if I do that enough time, the player gets angry, jumps to the clip's beginning and then it plays without a problem (so I know that there are no restrictions or anything).

An example can be seen here: http://www.playbuzz.com/shayc/cover-versions-whos-track-is-this-originally
This url is available on both desktop and mobile, I have issues only on mobile.

Is there anything that can be done to fix this?

Comment: Your URL worked perfectly for me on Chrome Mobile (running on KitKat). Do you have specific mobile browsers/platforms that it isn't running on?

Comment: Thanks, so apparently this is an issue with older versions of Android